# Logstash delete type and keep _type

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a logstash client and server.
The client sends logfiles with the udp output of logstash to the server and the server also runs logstash to get these logs. On the server, I have a json filter that pulls the json formatted message in the fields of the actual log, so that elasticsearch can index them.

Here is my code from the server:

```
input{
  udp{}
}

filter{
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}

output{
  elasticsearch{
  }
}
```

And from the client:

```
input{
  file{
    type => "apache-access"
    path => "/var/log/apache2/access.log"
  }
}

output{
  udp{
    host => "192.168.0.3"
  }
}
```

This code works fine except one thing:
In some way i get the field `type` twice, once as `type` and once as `_type`, they have the same content.

I've tried to delete the `type`-field with the `mutate`-filter like this:

```
mutate{
  remove_field => [ "type" ]
}
```

but this filter removes both `type` fields.(the `_type` field is set to default: *logs*)

How can I keep the `_type` field and remove the `type` field?

Comment: Can you give the full logstash configuration file...

Comment: @AnilkumarBathula This is all what matters, in the full config file are just more inputs, a different udp-port and a filter that is not related to this problem: `mutate{add_field=>{"program"=>"apache"}}`

Comment: I think these two fields are actually the same memory, and that `_type` is automatically outputted as "_logs_" if there is no `type` field in `_source`.

Comment: Yes @Klaus. But what i am thinking is how this `type` filed is created

Comment: @Anilkumar I think that setting type in the file-input sets the type in _source and the _type is just some kind of pointer to type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83733/discussion-between-anilkumar-bathula-and-klaus-prinoth).

Answer (score 3):

It works for me in this way:

```
input { 
    file {
        add_field => { "[@metadata][type]" => "apache-access" }
        path => "/var/log/apache2/access.log"
    }
}

filter {
    ......
    if [@metadata][type] == "xxx" {

    }
    ......
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }
}
```

@metadata and document_type