# Logstash is mixing up multiline logs

Tags: logging, logstash, logstash-forwarder

I am inputting logs using Logstash forwarder and using a multiline filter to build the logs into messages (each log is at least 2 lines). The problem is occasionally messages get mixed up.

An example of the file with 3 logs would be

Header1
Body1

Header2
Body2

Header3
Body3

But the logs may show up later as

Header1
Body2
Body1

Header2

Header3
Body3

I am using a stream_identity => "%{host}.%{path}.%{type}.%{file}", but since these two logs are part of the same file, this is not being violated.

This seems to be a problem based on the network traffic, as sometimes it parses all logs perfectly and sometimes it scrambles nearly all of them.

Is there any way I can guarantee that the logs will be built in the correct order?

Comment: Do you have multiple inputs?

Comment: The only input is lumberjack.

Comment: Why don't you use logstash on your client instead of logstash forwarder, add the multiline-filter there and put it to your server through logstash's build in udp-output/udp-input? So the logs can't be scrambled up.

Comment: I have done so and it works perfectly, if you like I'll post my config-files as an answer. Or you can find some of them in a [quetion I have asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512764/logstash-delete-type-and-keep-type).

Comment: I looked into that before but couldn't find many examples of people using it instead of logstash forwarder.   Logstash-forwarder with multiline works perfectly sometimes and horribly at other times.  I will try replacing logstash-forwarder with logstash if I can't find any fix for this issue.